# Symfony Form Error: "Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "Doctrine\ORM\Query" given"

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have two form inside the Controller the first form works fine however my second Form does not work as expected.

MyController:

```
// Second Form
$formTwo = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('form2name', new CarType(), null, array())
        ->getForm();

if('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

if ($request->request->has('form1name')) {
    // handle the first form  
}

if ($request->request->has('form2name')) {
    // handle the second form 
    // get the id value of the selected value. 
  }
}
```

My CarType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

   $builder->add('makename','entity',array(
                    'class'=> 'MyTestBundle:Car\CarModel',
                    'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er){
                        return $query = $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                    ->select('s.makename')
                                    ->distinct()
                                    ->orderBy('s.makename','ASC');
                }

   ));
  $builder->add('search','submit',array());
}
```

[My Car Entity](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/99b8d0048259d3ceaca1)

[Full Stack Trace](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/e75535e999565a579a13)

> Error : "Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "Doctrine\ORM\Query" given"

Symfony Version : 2.7

Comment: Remove the getQuery() and maybe change $query to $qb just to make it clear that you are dealing with a query builder object and not a query object.  Two very different things. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities.  You might get a different error.  Not sure what distinct will do to your query.  Have to try it and see.

Comment: Remove the `->getQuery()`. Without that you return the query builder, with it you return a query object. Also you can remove the `$query = ` as it's never used so redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `query_builder` (for building your form) you have to return a `QueryBuilder` object. Currently, you return a `Query` object.

Just remove `getQuery()`

```
 $builder->add('makename','entity',array(
                    'class'=> 'MyTestBundle:Car\CarModel',
                    'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er){
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                    ->select('s.makename')
                                    ->distinct()
                                    //->getQuery(); remove this line
                }
```

Comment: Also the assignation to the $query variable

Comment: I get a different Error now :  Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Comment: Ok, could you update your post and copy the full trace in order to know exactly when this error is thrown and what is this string, please ?

Comment: Ok I think it's because you are selecting only "makename" for an entity field link to your `CarType`. 

This query_builder does not return full object corresponding to "AUDI" (for example) but just "AUDI" string. You have to remove the select condition and adding a `__ToString()` method in CarModel entity to display `makename`. Can't say if it could match with `distinct` because it means that a Car could be linked to AUDI with id 10, for example, or to AUDI with id 25.. I think it's missing a **`CarBrand`** entity

Comment: yes because i want to create dynamic dropdown and "makename" is the first dropdown option and I think now it works... I removed "select" and added "choice_label"

 `$builder->add('makename', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyTestBundle:Car\CarModel',
            'choice_label'=>'makename',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->GroupBy('s.makename')
                    ->orderBy('s.makename','ASC');
            }
        )); `

Comment: And I also had to change from  `distinct() ` to  `GroupBy() ` and got it working... Thanks :)